# jquery if span contains this then hide this

Tags: jquery

i've created the script to locate 1 element and based on the find to hide different element.
thing is this is a catalogue so there are many DIVs with same items, IDs etc.
can the script be changed so it looks record by record rather to action all once 1 is found?

this is the HTML (2 items - bare in mind it might be many more)

```
<div class="katalog-record-container katalog-library-record">
    <div class="katalog-record">            
        <div class="katalog-record-details">
            <div class="katalog-record-media">
                <span class="katalog-field">Media class:</span>
                <span class="katalog-value">eBook</span>
            <div class="katalog-record-right">
                <div class="katalog-record-availability">
                    <a href="http://katalog-url/web/katalog/"><span class="katalog-available">Available for loan</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="katalog-record-container katalog-library-record">
    <div class="katalog-record">            
        <div class="katalog-record-details">
            <div class="katalog-record-media">
                <span class="katalog-field">Media class:</span>
                <span class="katalog-value">eAudio</span>
            <div class="katalog-record-right">
                <div class="katalog-record-availability">
                    <a href="http://katalog-url/web/katalog/"><span class="katalog-available">Available for loan</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="katalog-record-container katalog-library-record">
    <div class="katalog-record">            
        <div class="katalog-record-details">
            <div class="katalog-record-media">
                <span class="katalog-field">Media class:</span>
                <span class="katalog-value">eAudio</span>
            <div class="katalog-record-right">
                <div class="katalog-record-availability">
                    <a href="http://katalog-url/web/katalog/"><span class="katalog-available">Available for loan</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="katalog-record-container katalog-library-record">
    <div class="katalog-record">            
        <div class="katalog-record-details">
            <div class="katalog-record-media">
                <span class="katalog-field">Media class:</span>
                <span class="katalog-value">eBook</span>
            <div class="katalog-record-right">
                <div class="katalog-record-availability">
                    <a href="http://katalog-url/web/katalog/"><span class="katalog-available">Available for loan</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

script used:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> $(function () {
    var checkExist = setInterval(function () {
        if ($('.katalog-record-container.katalog-library-record .katalog-record-media span:contains("eBook")').length > 0) {
            $('.katalog-record-container.katalog-library-record .katalog-record-right').hide();
        }
        clearInterval(checkExist);
    }, 10);
});
</script>
```

but it looks like when it finds eBook it removes availability for all divs and it shouldn't as not all of them are eBooks

Please assist?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var checkExist = setInterval(function () {
        if ($('.katalog-record-container.katalog-library-record .katalog-record-media span:contains("eBook")').length > 0) {
        $('.katalog-record-container.katalog-library-record .katalog-record-media span:contains("eBook")').next().hide();  // Change this line only.
        }
        clearInterval(checkExist);
    }, 10);
});
```

I guess you want to hide "Available for loan" item that comes after span "eBook", then do this else explain your question.
Check this : https://jsfiddle.net/3cbc8jyb/

Comment: What do you want exactly ?

Comment: there are many records on the page, each record have it's own DIV so i want the script to look at them one by one and action separately one by one. if within the top DIV theres "eBook" then within the same div (and only that div) hide "Available for loan". then check next DIV etc. as some DIVs dont have word eBook so then the script would hide Available for loan. Hope thats clear :)

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the divs containing the spans. This is working code:

```
$(function() {
  $.each($('.katalog-record-media'), function() {
    if ($(this).children('.katalog-value').text()==='eBook') {
      $(this).children('.katalog-record-right').hide();
    }
  })
});
```

and here a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j7jw31or/1/

Comment: sorry not sure why maybe more scipts conflicting with this one but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

this code works fine but removes the wording from all top divs and i want to modify this so looks at the DIVs separately one by one and then removes the working only in the DIV that the word is found - sorry just trying to make this clear and i don't think i'm helping :) over describing it!!

```
$(function() {
      var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
          if ($('.katalog-record-media span:contains("eBook")').length > 0) {
            $('.katalog-record-right').hide();
          }
          clearInterval(checkExist);
        }, 10);
      });
```

by the way checkExist is important as the text might not be there from the start.